# Drawing edited vertex value from VBO

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I probably do something really stupid so go ahead and correct me.
I'm trying to make vertex move so...

In `OnLoad` I'm setting the VBO like you see.
In `OnFrameRender` I'm trying to edit vertex then i do `drawArrays`.
But i can't get this changes be visible in OpenTk window. Doing `ConsoleWrite(prymi.vertOne)` shows me that struct is edited (i do get sin from 0 to 20) so I'm assuming that this values are not updated on GPU. I tryed every VBO `BufferUsageHint` (Dynamic/Static/Stream(Copy/Draw/Read)) and this is not the case. I have read that i should use `BufferSubData` (i don't know about this concept yet(so any help would be helpful) but editing the object which is passed as reference with VBO `StreamDraw` should also do it... or em i wrong?
Thanks all :)

```
struct TrianglePrymi
{

    public Vector2 vertOne;

    public Vector2 vertSec;

    public Vector2 VertThird;

    public TrianglePrymi(Vector2 fi, Vector2 sec, Vector2 thi )
    {
        vertOne = fi;
        vertSec = sec;
        VertThird = thi;
    }
    public void edit(Vector2 a)
    {
        vertOne = a;
    }
    public static int retSize()
    {
        return (3 * Vector2.SizeInBytes);
    }

}
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {

        prymi = new TrianglePrymi(new Vector2(20,20),new Vector2(300,200), new Vector2(530,420));
        ttttt = TrianglePrymi.retSize();
        VBO = GL.GenBuffer();
        GL.BindVertexArray(VAO);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VBO);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)ttttt,ref prymi, BufferUsageHint.DynamicDraw);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
        base.OnLoad(e);

    }



    protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prymi.vertOne[0]);
        //Console.WriteLine(prymi.vertSec);
        //Console.WriteLine(prymi.VertThird);
        magicNumber += 1.00f;
        float x = Math.Abs(20 * (float)Math.Sin(magicNumber));
        float y = Math.Abs(20 * (float)Math.Cos(magicNumber));


        GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.VertexArray);
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit|ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);





        GL.ClearColor(Color.Gray);

        prymi.edit(new Vector2(x, y));
        Vector2 vec = new Vector2(magicNumber, 450);
        Matrix4 world = Matrix4.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0, widX, 0, heiY, 0, 2000);
        GL.LoadMatrix(ref world);

        GL.Color3(Color.Yellow);
        prymi.vertOne = vec;
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VBO);

        GL.VertexPointer(2, VertexPointerType.Float,Vector2.SizeInBytes, 0);

        GL.DrawArrays(BeginMode.Triangles, 0, 3);

        GL.End();
        GL.Flush();
        base.OnRenderFrame(e);
        this.SwapBuffers();
    }
```

Comment: *"I'm trying to make vertex move"* - The common way to "move" a mesh is to use and change the model matrix.

Comment: I know that and in the future i will experiment with the world matrix and projection matrix, but now, i'm looking for editing vertex vector in VBO!

Comment: *but editing the object which is passed as reference with VBO `StreamDraw` should also do it... or em i wrong?* - Yes you are wrong. `StreamDraw` is a hint for the buffer usage, but doesn't provide a persistent buffer. You would have to use [Buffer Mapping](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object#Mapping) with a persistent buffer

Comment: Use [`GL.BufferSubData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/opentk.graphics.es30.gl.buffersubdata?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) to change the content of the buffer.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks gonna read about it <3